# Django.conf module not found, why?

Tags: django, module

I'm trying to install the Evennia Python MUD and when I get to the python manage.py syncdb command I get the below message... any ideas on why?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evennia.py", line 33, in ?
    from django.conf import settings
ImportError: No module named django.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

An `ImportError` exception happens when Python cannot import a particular module.  Usually it's because that module doesn't appear in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

So, in your case, you need to add the path to `django.conf` to your `PYTHONPATH`.

Here's a great write-up on several different ways of accomplishing this:

http://docs.webfaction.com/software/python.html#importerror

Edited: corrected typo--`django.conf` should be added to the path, not `evennia.py`, thanks Yuji.

Comment: The `ImportError` is for `django.conf`, not `evennia`, and the strange thing is that `manage.py` should throw a `django.core.management` ImportError first if django wasn't on the path.

Comment: Scratch that, the evennia settings.py will first attempt to import django.conf before django management. Still, he needs to add `django` to the path.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the .pyc files using the command

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

and test again.

Answer (score 1):

You will get this if you just haven't installed Django.

e.g.

```
pip install django
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to do manual stuff of changing the path and might create some more problems so instead go to your environment and delete "bin" folder and "pip-selfchek.json" now re-create your env with whatever method you want to use. i generally use

```
virtualenv -p python3 <envname>
```

now activate the env, and check all your package by

```
pip freeze
```

all good to go.