# Subterfuge django.conf error

Tags: python, django

I followed all installation steps for installing subterfuge ( http://kinozoa.com/blog/subterfuge-documentation/ ) but at the end, while executing "subterfuge" command, i get:

```
root@kali:/usr/share/subterfuge# subterfuge
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/subterfuge", line 11, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
ImportError: No module named django.conf
```

any ideas?

Comment: check if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904895/django-conf-module-not-found-why

Comment: this one too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538903/celery-and-django-no-module-named-django