# No module named django.conf

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, django-wsgi

I am trying to restart django process on my server using this command:

```
gunicorn projectname.wsgi
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 366, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/root/xxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
    from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whitenoise/django.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
ImportError: No module named django.conf
```

any idea where to go from there?

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904895/django-conf-module-not-found-why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904895/django-conf-module-not-found-why)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django.conf module not found, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904895/django-conf-module-not-found-why)

Comment: this basically says that django is not installed. if you're using virtualenv make sure you are in the virtualenv when running gunicorn. Or add the correct environment variables to your gunicorn command so that it knows where to find django.

Comment: I've tried to install django but that didn't solve it